# On selecting one item of <datalist> other datalist should open according to the selected item of first datalist

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-forms

"I am making an inquiry model form. I have created datalist widget already. Now what I want is that on selecting the item from datalist, one more datalist should appear on the basis of the item selected in first datalist. "
from below suppose i select USA then some cities of usa should appear on new data list or if i select China some citys of china should appear.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .fields import ListTextWidget

class FormForm(forms.Form):
   data = ('Mexico', 'USA', 'India', 'France')
   char_field_with_list = forms.CharField(required=True)
   char_field_with  = forms.CharField(required=True,widget = ListTextWidget(data_list=data,name='data'))


   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      _country_list = kwargs.pop('data_list', None)
      super(FormForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['char_field_with_list'].widget = ListTextWidget(data_list=_country_list, name='country-list')
```

field.py (where a widget is created)
from django import forms

```
class ListTextWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self, data_list, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListTextWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._name = name
        self._list = data_list
        self.attrs.update({'list':'list__%s' % self._name})

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        text_html = super(ListTextWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs=attrs)
        data_list = '<datalist id="list__%s">' % self._name
        for item in self._list:
            data_list += '<option value="%s">' % item
        data_list += '</datalist>'

        return (text_html + data_list)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .forms import FormForm

def country_form(request):
    # instead of hardcoding a list you could make a query of a model, as long as
    # it has a __str__() method you should be able to display it.
    country_list = ('Mexico', 'USA', 'China', 'France')
    form = FormForm(data_list=country_list)

    return render(request, 'inquiry/inquiry.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: you're not showing a specific problem, you 're asking how to build something where you haven't tried yourself. There isn't even a list of cities in the code you're showing. Please see [ask] to learn how to make your question more precise.

Comment: @dirkgroten thankyou